# New Minecraft proposed Site. What do you guys think?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

I just [proposed a new site on Area 51.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127147/minecraft?referrer=MzY3Y2M0ZWZlZWRiZDUwOTc1NDk2MDdmMDNhZGU5ODE5ZmI1ZTA2ZjdjYjIxY2JkYTdmY2U3ZGM3NmNhN2MzMEM-QUwkRGfI0hO2ksegeQkdhpOKsiE7U8vThPNoOCqC0) It is about Minecraft, and I would like to know if it is possible to move all Minecraft questions from this site to that site (assuming that site gets made). And then all the people that asked about this should create an account on the new site (if that is possible)?

What do you guys think? Is this new site even a good idea or not? I was wondering if questions on this site would be accepted on Arqade if this would make the new site irrelevant.

Also, I need more proposed questions and followers of this proposed site within three days or it will die.

Comment: Please stop just downvoting. I know it doesn't affect my rep score, but please add a comment telling me what you think. I want some feedback here, not just some random downvotes.

Comment: Related: [Separate site for Minecraft](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/separate-site-for-minecraft) and [When does it become necessary to create a new community for a specific game?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/when-does-it-become-necessary-to-create-a-new-community-for-a-specific-game)

Comment: See also: [this chat search result for "minecraft" when said by a feed that posts new Area 51 proposals](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft&user=-178&room=35)

Comment: Oh boy. That's a lot of proposals. Are they all closed except for mine now? Thanks for the links, but what do **you** think about this? Good idea? Bad? Would you like to follow the proposed site?

Comment: Im no expert of A51 but usually, when a thing is solidly on topic on an existing site, we dont open a new site for that thing in particular. So thats why its downvoted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minecraft is in-scope here. Always has been, always will be. This is a [periodic proposal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft&user=-178&room=35), but at the end of the day, Arqade is well equipped to handle Minecraft questions, and your proposal will probably be closed as a duplicate of Arqade soon.

Comment: Depressing answer because I would have like to create a different site for this, but +1 and accepted anyways. Thanks I guess...

Comment: Welp, exactly what you expected happened. My proposal got closed. I guess I'll stop trying to push this new site.

Answer (score 6):

The other things to consider in addition to the other answer is your proposed site excludes mods, which is a massive part of Minecraft. Even if we could move our Minecraft questions to this new site, how would we accurately move vanilla questions versus modded questions?

It would also probably create a huge amount of questions that would only end up closed because Minecraft is no longer allowed on our site. It would create a lot of work, considering [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) is our #1 tag (and then complicate this further with Bedrock edition, and the other smaller ones).

Comment: I'll admit, I too have thought about a dedicated Minecraft SE site, but knowing Arqade exists, it doesn't make sense to implement. Maybe before the dawn of Arqade (which I think only barely predates Minecraft), a Minecraft site might have worked.

Comment: Wait, Minecraft is no longer allowed? What happened?

Comment: Also I added modded questions in the proposal as long as they are tagged as modded.

Comment: @Enderman I was talking about if your proposed site were to become live.  Minecraft questions are still allowed.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks, I was confused for a sec.

Comment: For what it's worth, Arqade was first proposed on June 1, 2010, and, per [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition_version_history), "Java Edition has been in constant development since mid-May 2009", so Minecraft predates Arqade by almost a year.

Comment: @pppery I thought it wasn't really a thing until 2011. No matter